# How to make ng-options to run after it is enabled?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I have these two dropdown element and the output of second will depend on input of first. The second drop down will take input of first drop down as ( `ng-options="reason for reason in getReason($ctrl.selectedItem)`)
However I realized the second dropdown will not wait for first drop down to be selected and run the `ng-options` but since it takes input from first. It causes `null` error.

How do I solve this issue?

```js
class Items{
  constructor(){
       this.items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
       this.selectedItem = null;
       this.stuff = {
          "item1" : ["asdd"],
          "item2" : ["asdasdsd", "asdsddd],
          "item3" : ["asdasdasd]
       };
  }
  getReason(item){
    return this.stuff[item];
  }
}
```

```html
<select ng-model=“$ctrl.selectedItem” ng-options=“item for item in items”>
</select>
<select  ng-disabled=“!$ctrl.selectedItem” ng-options=“reason for reason in getReason($ctrl.selectedItem)”>
```

Comment: If this may be an options, try adding `ng-if` to second select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `getReason` in order to return an empty array if `item` is not a "valid" argument.

```
getReason(item){
    item ? return this.stuff[item] : [];
}
```

*Note*: This will keep the second dropdown empty until the `item` argument is valid.